# getting the date in the outfile of mysql query in node js code

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to achieve writing a outfile in sql including the timestamp.:

```
sql query:SET @TS = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'_%Y_%m_%d_%H_%i_%s');
SET @FOLDER = 'now';
SET @EXT    = '.csv';
SET @CMD = CONCAT("SELECT * FROM test.extract INTO     OUTFILE'",@FOLDER,@TS,@EXT,"' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY     '\n';");
PREPARE statement FROM @CMD;
EXECUTE statement;
```

If I give the same query in the node js script given below it is failing. can someone help.

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host     : 'localhost',
user     : 'root',
password : 'root',
database : 'test'
});

connection.connect();

var timeInMs = Date.now();
console.log(timeInMs);


connection.query("SET @TS = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'_%Y_%m_%d_%H_%i_%s');
SET @FOLDER = 'now';
SET @EXT    = '.csv';
SET @CMD = CONCAT(
"SELECT * FROM test.extract INTO OUTFILE'",@FOLDER,@TS,@EXT,"' FIELDS     TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';");

PREPARE statement FROM @CMD;
EXECUTE statement;",function(err, rows, fields) {
if (!err)
  console.log('The solution is: ', rows);
else
  console.log('Error while performing Query.');
});
connection.end();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#multiple-statement-queries) of the `mysql` nodejs module:

> Support for multiple statements is disabled for security reasons (it
>   allows for SQL injection attacks if values are not properly escaped).
>   To use this feature you have to enable it for your connection:
>
> ```
> var connection = mysql.createConnection({multipleStatements: true});
> ```

Also, for multi-line to work properly, put it in backticks. The following code works for me:

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host     : 'localhost',
user     : 'root',
password : 'root',
database : 'test',
multipleStatements: true
});

connection.connect();

var timeInMs = Date.now();
console.log(timeInMs);

connection.query(`SET @TS = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'_%Y_%m_%d_%H_%i_%s'); 
SET @FOLDER = 'now';
SET @EXT  = '.csv';
SET @CMD = CONCAT(
"SELECT * FROM mysql.user INTO OUTFILE'",@FOLDER,@TS,@EXT,"' FIELDS     TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';");
PREPARE statement FROM @CMD;
EXECUTE statement;`    
,function(err, rows, fields) {
if (!err)
  console.log('The solution is: ', rows);
else
  console.log('Error while performing Query.', err);
});
connection.end();
```

Comment: Thanks Nehal,I also have another question. I am trying to query a database like joining multiple tables and having case's in my code. how do I call that query in my code?

Comment: Sorry. I used the back quotes and achieved it.

Comment: Hi Nehal,can you answer this question for me please. I am trying to use fs.appendfile but not able to troubleshoot it. Please help.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42401423/mysql-data-need-to-be-written-to-a-json-file